# Making point buffer map on web

Tags: buffer, web-mapping, software-recommendations

I am looking for a tool like Google Maps Engine Lite or Mapbox where I can draw a simple (buffer) circle around a point with a known diameter.

**Are there any quick and easy web mapping tools to draw a single circle and share?**

For example, someone on a forums says, "Show me what a 10 mile ban on kite-flying would look like?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a free ArcGIS Online account, using its [web maps](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/what-is-web-map.htm) feature.

After you create a new web map, you can search for the address where you'd like to create a point and then add it as a point using map notes ([documentation here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/map-notes.htm)).

Once the point is created, you can buffer it using the web map analysis tools. Select the proximity tools, then choose Create Buffers ([documentation here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/create-buffers.htm)). From there you can configure the buffer distance and generate it.